# does a compound index in MongoDB improve multified match (not sorting)?

Tags: performance, mongodb, sorting, indexing, compound-index

The documentation seems a bit unclear on that.

1)It clearly states that compound indexes DO improve performance of multi-field SORTING (order and direction dependant).

2) There is one phrase which makes me think it will **also** improve multi field MACH (sql analogy: where a=1 and b=2 and c<5)

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/

> If a query searches multiple fields, create a compound index.

it says nothing about sorting.

So is compound index on fields a,b,c better for matching performance than three single-field indexes for queries like (where a=1 and b=2 and c<5)?

Comment: okay i did some explains() and found out that it DOES prefer compond index in a sortless query than single field ones

Comment: Normally speaking the more it can match before consulting the actual collection the better. There are exceptions to hat of course, but they normally apply cross database, i.e. in SQL and MongoDB equally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, creating compound indexes improve query performance.

> Create a Single-Key Index if All Queries Use the Same, Single Key

If for a particular collection you are using a single key for matching like `where a=1`

> Create Compound Indexes to Support Several Different Queries

If your query uses one or more than one key, it better to use compound indexes.

```
db.sample.createIndex( { "a": 1, "b": 1, "c":1 } )
```

You can query on just a, you can query on a combined with b and also you can query on a, b and c. You can use explain() method to get to know what plan your query is using.

[Index Intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/) might also optimize the performance of your queries. It can support what compound index fails to support.

Comment: "It can supports what compound index fails to support." Doesn't index intersectioning actually support less than compound indexes, for example with match and sort, plus isn't it actually much slower than a specifically designed index?

Comment: @Sammaye you are correct, index intersection doesn't work when the matching key is different from the sorting key. because both the list order and the sort order, matter in compound indexes, a compound index may not support a query condition that does not include the index prefix keys or that specifies a different sort order but in such cases index intersection works well.

Comment: Hmmm... You know, isn't getting in such details TOO much trouble to get basic searchng to work? I'm starting to think about not using mongo for any kind of search, and move this functionality to dedicated host running Sphinx. I really hope (and basing on my not very big experience it is) that I will be able to get good quiery performance without getting in such intricate detail. What do you say?

Comment: @user1312695 this is intricate? This is standard stuff every db user should know, even in Sphinx as well. You cannot make effective queries if you do not understand the full nature of your storage tech

Comment: @Sammaye: Actually, I fully agree with you. )

Comment: btw, if i frequenlty search by fields (a,b,c,d) together, as well as (a,b) do I have to create two compound indexes: one for combination of four fields, and another - for just a and b?  wont the 'bigger' index be enough to support queries over the "subset" of its fields?

Comment: @user1312695 since a.b is a prefix of a,b,c,d single compound index of a,b,c,d will suffice